# wrong enumeration with parnotes inside tabu environment

Tags: tabu, parnotes

`pdflatex` compiles the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,vmargin=3cm,hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}, 
        %linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{parnotes}
\renewcommand{\parnotevskip}{0.5ex}
\renewcommand{\parnoteintercmd}{\\}
\setlength\parindent{0em}
\setlength\parskip{1.5ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabu}{@{}X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[2.5c]X[c]}
    \toprule[2pt]
    \bfseries Hersteller &
    \bfseries Pro"-dukt"-be"-zeich"-nung &
    \bfseries Akku"-mu"-lator"-typ &
    \bfseries Preis/\euro &
    \bfseries Lebensdauer in Ladezyklen bezogen auf Entladung von 4,5Ah &
    \bfseries Cents/ Ladezyklus
    \\ \midrule
    %http://www.reichelt.de/Blei-Vlies-Akkus-12V-Kung-Long/WP-5-12/3/index.html?;ACTION=3;LA=2;ARTICLE=130548;GROUPID=4232;artnr=WP+5-12
    Kung Long & WP 5-12 & Blei-Vlies-Akku & 17,90\parnote{eins}  & 200 & 8,95 \\
    %http://www.pollin.de/shop/dt/NjI5ODI3OTk-/Stromversorgung/Akkus/Blei_Akkus/LiFePO4_Akku_VISION_LFP124_5T_12_V_5_Ah.html
    Vision & LFP124.5T & LiFePO4-Akku & 93,50\parnote{zwei} & 2000 & 4,68 \\
    %http://www.reichelt.de/Blei-Vlies-Akkus-12V-zyklisch/LC-CA-1215P1/3/index.html?;ACTION=3;LA=3;ARTICLE=77912;GROUPID=4235
    Panasonic & LC-CA 1215P1 & Blei-Vlies-Akku & 39,95\parnote{drei} & 1400 & 2,85\\
    \bottomrule[2pt]
    \end{tabu}
    \raggedright
    \parnotes
    \caption{dies ist ein Text}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

to

[image: compiled version]

---

Of course i want `parnotes` to start the enumeration from 1 and stop it if it reaches 3.

Unfortunately it seems, that the content inside the `tabu` environment is processed three times and i don't find a way how to achieve the intended result.
Since i have several `table` environments of this kind in my document i don't want to give up the automatic enumeration provided by `parnotes`.

Maybe anyone can give me a tip or show me a workaround that yields the desired output!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both `tabularx`  and I think `tabu` allow you to use the normal `\footnote` command to make table notes and protect that command from being executed multiple times. So not using `\parnotes` is a realistic option.

If you want to use `\parnotes` then there are a couple of bugs to fix and then you need to add some connection to the table trials.

```
% Counter for parnote marks left by \parnote
\global\newcount\c@PN@t
% Counter for parnote marks *within* parnotes
\global\newcount\c@PN@n
```

`\global` before `\newcount doesn't do anything useful, but this isn't a full emulation of the latex counter declaration, if this is replaced by

```
% Counter for parnote marks left by \parnote
\newcounter{PN@t}
% Counter for parnote marks *within* parnotes
\newcounter{PN@n}
```

The table macros with "know" about these counters and reset them while doing trial settings of the table.

that is enough to avoid the counter increasing beyond 3 however you then need to add some code to tell the table macros not to save the text during trial runs. For `tabularx` this works

```
\long\def\parnote{%
\relax\ifx\@footnotetext\TX@trial@ftn\else
    \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\PN@parnote@real
    \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@gobble
    \fi
\fi
}
```

I had a quick look at the tabu internals but didn't immediately spot what the corresponding test would be.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,vmargin=3cm,hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}, 
        %linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{parnotes}
\renewcommand{\parnotevskip}{0.5ex}
\renewcommand{\parnoteintercmd}{\\}
\setlength\parindent{0em}
\setlength\parskip{1.5ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}\textwidth{@{}
*4{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.7\hsize}X}
>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=2.5\hsize}X
>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.7\hsize}X}
    \toprule[2pt]
    \bfseries Hersteller &
    \bfseries Pro"-dukt"-be"-zeich"-nung &
    \bfseries Akku"-mu"-lator"-typ &
    \bfseries Preis/\euro &
    \bfseries Lebensdauer in Ladezyklen bezogen auf Entladung von 4,5Ah &
    \bfseries Cents/ Ladezyklus
    \\ \midrule
    %http://www.reichelt.de/Blei-Vlies-Akkus-12V-Kung-Long/WP-5-12/3/index.html?;ACTION=3;LA=2;ARTICLE=130548;GROUPID=4232;artnr=WP+5-12
    Kung Long & WP 5-12 & Blei-Vlies-Akku & 17,90\parnote{eins}  & 200 & 8,95 \\
    %http://www.pollin.de/shop/dt/NjI5ODI3OTk-/Stromversorgung/Akkus/Blei_Akkus/LiFePO4_Akku_VISION_LFP124_5T_12_V_5_Ah.html
    Vision & LFP124.5T & LiFePO4-Akku & 93,50\parnote{zwei} & 2000 & 4,68 \\
    %http://www.reichelt.de/Blei-Vlies-Akkus-12V-zyklisch/LC-CA-1215P1/3/index.html?;ACTION=3;LA=3;ARTICLE=77912;GROUPID=4235
    Panasonic & LC-CA 1215P1 & Blei-Vlies-Akku & 39,95\parnote{drei} & 1400 & 2,85\\
    \bottomrule[2pt]
    \end{tabularx}
    \raggedright
    \parnotes
    \caption{dies ist ein Text}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort you put in your detailed answer! This solved my problem...